# How to make https optional in lightning input type url in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, url, lightninginput

I want to make https or http optional in my url type input field. But I always get invalid format error. I've tried regex pattern as well, but no luck.

```
HTML Code:

<lightning-input type="url" value={value} class="slds-p-horizontal--xx-small" variant="label-hidden"  pattern="((ftp|http|https):\/\/)?" name="input1" onblur={updateValue} onchange={updateValue} disabled={isdisabled}></lightning-input>

JS Code:

updateValue(event) {
   this.value = event.target.value;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "url" type has its own validations, and you can't bypass these. If you want a freeform text where the user doesn't need to put in a complete URL, use "text" instead, and you can use a pattern to specify exactly what you expect as a regular expression.